# Monitoring Pm2 instances in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, monitoring, pm2

I'm running NodeJS application on Pm2 in a container environment(Docker) and would like to add better monitoring like if any instance is not working it will show in the tool, dashboard, instances are getting restarted and health of instances etc. I'm aware about Pm2 Keymentrics but it is costly. So, is there is any other tool which provides Pm2 monitoring and also dashboard ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most populars are New Relic and Datadog, but both are paid, and both are APMs (application performance management). Or if you want to save metrics you can use Opencensus with Prometheus which is a monitor.